# Vendor information of network interface in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I develop Linux netfilter kernel module and need retrieve vendor information of network card, something like:
"Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
or
"Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205"

I have available net_device structure. Is possible to retrieve such description from net_device in kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

This can be done from userspace only, the kernel does not keep such information. However, you *can* retrieve the vendor id and product id of the device. For that, you need to know more about the PCI subsystem. And the combination of vendor id and product id, sometimes with subvendor and subproduct id, determine the device identity.